# How to make the image height proportionally change the height and width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I use Owl-carousel and ran into a problem that at a small screen resolution the width of the picture decreases, but the height remains the same. How do I make the width and height decrease equally? for the .gal-slide and .owl-item block I have the height set to 350px

Code https://jsfiddle.net/tmavoerp/

Site  https://ct61276.tmweb.ru/

[image]

```js
$(".gallery-slider.owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        autoplay: false,
        items: 3,
        slideSpeed: 2000,
        autoHeight: true,
        loop: true,
        nav: true,
        navText: ["<i class='fas fa-arrow-left'></i>", "<i class='fas fa-arrow-right'></i>"],
        center: true,
        dots: false,
        responsiveClass: true,
        smartSpeed: 800,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items:  1.7,
                margin: 30,
                center: true
            },
            730: {
                items: 2,
                margin: 130,
                center: false
            },


            790: {
                items: 2.5,
                margin: 60,
            },

            1050: {
                items: 3,
                 margin: 60

            }
        },
    });
```

```css
.gallery {
  max-height: 600px;
}
.gallery .gall-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gallery-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.gallery-block .title-block {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: -116px;
}
.gallery-slider {
  left: -310px;
}
.gallery-slider .gal-slide {
  height: 350px !important;
  width: 350px;
}
.gallery-slider .owl-stage {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 600px !important;
}
.gallery-slider .owl-stage-outer {
  overflow: visible !important;
  height: 600px !important;
}
.gallery-slider .owl-item {
  height: 350px;
  transition: 1.3s;
}
.gallery-slider .owl-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  transition: 1.3s !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<section class="gallery">
        <div class="gall-wrap">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="gallery-block">
                        <div class="title-block">
                            <div class="forehead">Frispes gallery</div>
                            <h3>Immersive beautiful<br>co-working space gallery</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery-slider owl-carousel owl-loaded owl-drag">
                            
                                <div class="gal-slide">
                                    <img src="img/gal-1.jpg" alt="1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="gal-slide">
                                    <img src="img/gal-2.jpg" alt="2">
                                </div>
                                <div class="gal-slide">
                                    <img src="img/gal-3.jpg" alt="3">
                                </div>
                                <div class="gal-slide">
                                    <img src="img/gal-4.jpg" alt="4">
                                </div>
                                <div class="gal-slide">
                                    <img src="img/gal-5.jpg" alt="5">
                                </div>
                                <div class="gal-slide">
                                    <img src="img/gal-6.jpg" alt="6">
                                </div>
                          

                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Can you fix the references to the images to better illustrate your issue using a service like https://picsum.photos/?

Comment: I know nothing about owl-carousel, but I can't help but notice there's a configuration item named `autoHeight` set to true there, but you set the `height` with `!important` on all of the images. Maybe that conflict is causing the problem?

Comment: uploaded the image here https://ibb.co/fHYsDVK

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aspect-ratio property in CSS so that the image always has the same ratio. Here 's how to use it:

```css
div{aspect-ratio: 1/1;}
```

this is for a square. After defining the aspect-ratio if you change anyone either the width or the height, the div or the image will scale only according to the aspect ratio. Here is the MDN [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio)